# How to get array of object's keys and values in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powercli

I have an array of object in a below format

```
$test = @(2 :{1,3,5}, 3 : {2,4,6})
```

I want to extract objects of keys and values from $test array.

Here is my powershell script to perform the above task,

```
$testnumbers = @(2,3)
$testStores = @{}
$testInfo = $null
foreach ($tn in $testnumbers) {
    $testInfo = @{}
    for($i=0;$i -lt $tn;$i = $i+1) {
    $testPrompt = Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the test numbers"
    $testInfo += $testPrompt
    }
$testInfoSet = {$tn = $testInfo}
$testInfoObj = New-Object psobject –Property $testInfoSet
$testStores += $testInfoObj
}
```

Please provide a solution, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `$test` value is syntactically invalid. You probably meant to use a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), which is created with `@{ ... }`, not `@(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may want to setup your hashtable like so...

```
$test = @{2 = (1,3,5); 3 = (2,4,6)}

foreach($item in $test.GetEnumerator()){
    echo $item.key
    echo $item.value
}
```

Comment: As an aside: While `Write-Output`, whose built-in alias is `echo`, is the right tool for outputting data, you typically don't need to use it explicitly, because PowerShell _implicitly_ outputs (to the success data stream) any expression or command that isn't captured or redirected; e.g., just `$foo` _by itself_ has the same effect as `Write-Output $foo` / `echo $foo`.
While there is no harm in using `Write-Output`, consider showcasing PowerShell's implicit output feature instead (possibly with an explanatory comment), so as to promote PowerShell-idiomatic solutions.

Comment: Glad to hear we agree, but I suggest you actually update your answer with this information, for the benefit of future readers. Once you have done so, you can flag my first and this comment as "No longer needed" (or ping me, so I can remove them myself).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @dno and the comments.
I have added to this with the output so you can see it working as explained.

```
$test = @{2 = (1,3,5);3 = (2,4,6);}

foreach($item in $test.GetEnumerator()){
    $key = $item.key
    $value = $item.value
    Write-Output $key $value
}
```